# Extend router network using Raspberry Pi 3 as access point

Tags: raspbian, networking, pi-3, chromecast

I currently am using [this guide](https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/) to create an access point using the RPI3 to create a new network, but what I would like is to extend the network to which the RPI3 is connected via Ethernet so that it acts as the same network, i.e. devices on the networks should see each other. Specifically, I would like my Chromecast to be connected to the RPI3 network and have it be controllable on the original network from the main router. Thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridging_(networking) You do not mention an operating system, but presuming Raspbian or some other form of GNU/Linux this is not that hard to implement, I think, and there should be mountains of examples around (just in case someone doesn't come along and hand it to you here).

Comment: I have my Pi 3 doing this running Arch Linux.